# Cant export multiple Sequelize Models from single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js

I have 3 sequelize models that i have defined imported into a file called `sequelize.js` like so:

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const UserModel = require("./models/user");
const ItemModel = require("./models/item");
const ReservationModel = require("./models/reservation");
const config = require("./dbconfig");
const db = config.database;

const Item = ItemModel(sequelize, Sequelize);
const User = UserModel(sequelize, Sequelize);
const Reservation = ReservationModel(sequelize, Sequelize);

Reservation.hasMany(Item);
Item.belongsTo(Reservation);
Reservation.belongsTo(User);
```

I then try to export them:

```
module.exports = { Item, User, Reservation };
```

However, when I try to access one of them and use a model function, I get an error.

```
const Model = require("../../sequelize");
const passport = require("passport");

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post("/registerUser", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("register", (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      if (info !== undefined) {
        console.log(info.message);
        res.send(info.message);
      } else {
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          const data = {
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            email: req.body.email,
            username: user.email,
          };
          Model.User.findOne({
            where: {
              email: data.username,
            },
          }).then((user) => {
            user
              .update({
                first_name: data.first_name,
                last_name: data.last_name,
                email: data.email,
              })
              .then(() => {
                console.log("user created in db");
                res.status(200).send({ message: "user created" });
              });
          });
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
};
```

results in

```
TypeError: User.findOne is not a function
```

This is not an issue when I just export one of them.

```
module.exports = User;
```

```
const User = require("./sequelize");
...
User.findOne(...) //works
```

I've tried multiple ways of exporting, but none seem to work.
e.g

```
module.exports = {
    Item: Item,
    User: User,
    Reservation: Reservation,
}
```

and

```
exports.Item = Item;
exports.User = User;
exports.Reservation = Reservation;
```

edit: Here is my user model for reference

```
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
  return sequelize.define(
    "user",
    {
      id: {
        type: type.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      first_name: type.STRING,
      last_name: type.STRING,
      credentials: type.STRING,
      email: {
        type: type.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: {
        type: type.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: "Users",
    }
  );
};
```

Why cant I export these multiple objects?

Comment: By the way: the User.findOne() is inside a passport.authenticate() call. I'm not sure if that would have anything to do with the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact structure you're using by importing all sequelize models into one file then module.exporting them in an object and the only thing I see thats different is how you define your models. I might be out of date but I learned as such:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db');

module.exports = db.define('users', {
    id: {
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
        unique: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

Db declaration

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const db = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    logging: false
  }
);
module.exports = db;
```

Then your central import

```
const User = require('./user');
const Order = require('./order');

Order.belongsTo(User)
User.hasMany(Order)

module.exports = {
    User,
    Order
};
```

Then using it

```
const models = require('./models');
const results = await models.User.destroy({
    where: {
        id: id
    }
});
if(results){
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not really sure if how I define my models have anything to do with it. Everything works fine when I only export User, however when I export all 3 Models things don't work.

Comment: I edited my post to add some more context around my code. Hopefully that'll clear things up some more

Answer (score 0):

Found what was wrong. In my passport.js file, where I defined my localStrategy, I was doing an incorrect import.

My export in sequelize.js was

```
modules.export = {Item, User, Reservation};
```

while my import in passport.js was just

```
const User = require("../sequelize");
```

when it should have been

```
const Model = require("../sequelize");
const User = Model.User;
```

looks like I had it imported correctly in my signUp route, but not in my passport config file!